# json data not displayed in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am creating jqgrid but the area where the json load shows undefined.

I am not able to figure out why data is displayed as undefined.
Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "../ShowUploadedCSVFile",
        success : function(response) {
            showJQgrid(response);
        },
        error : function() {
            alert("Failure");
        }
    });
    function showJQgrid(Data)
    {
        $("#showCSVList").jqGrid("clearGridData");
        var grid = $('#showCSVList');
        if (grid[0].grid == undefined) 
        {
        } 
        else 
        {
            delete grid;
            $('#showCSVList').GridUnload('#showCSVList');
        }
        var parse = Data;
        global = parse;
        var Jsj = eval('(' + parse + ')');
        var colNames = new Array();
        var colModel = new Array();
        var j = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < Jsj.Header.length; i++) 
        {
            colNames.push(Jsj.Header[i]);
            colModel.push({
                name : Jsj.Header[i],
                index : Jsj.Header[i],
                width : '75%',
                align : 'left',
                editable : true
            });
        }
        $('#showCSVList').jqGrid({
            datatype : 'local',
            colNames : colNames,
            colModel : colModel,
            scrollOffset : 0,
            pager : '#showCSVPager',
            rowNum : 5,
            loadonce : true,
            multiselect : true,
            rowList : [ 5, 10, 20, 50 ],
            viewrecords : true

        });
        for ( var i = 0; i < Jsj.data.length; i++) 
        {
            jQuery("#showCSVList").jqGrid('addRowData', i+1, Jsj.data[i]);
        }
        $("#showCSVList").jqGrid('setGridHeight', $("#center").height());
        $("#showCSVList").navGrid("#showCSVPager", {
            edit : false,
            add : false,
            del : true
        });
        $("#showCSVList").jqGrid('inlineNav', "#showCSVPager");
    }
});
```

My Json File is:

```
{
    "Header": ["Name", "Party", "Province", "Age", "Gender"],
    "data": [{
        "Name": "Mourani, Maria",
        "Age": "43",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Party": "BlocQuebecois",
        "Province": "Quebec"
    }, {
        "Name": "Sellah,Djaouida",
        "Age": "30",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Party": "NDP",
        "Province": "Quebec"
    }, {
        "Name": "St-Denis,Lise",
        "Age": "72",
        "Gender": "Female",
        "Party": "NDP",
        "Province": "Quebec"
    }]
}
```

The output generated by this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following lines;

```
var parse = Data;
global = parse;
var Jsj = eval('(' + parse + ')');
```

Since you are working with json data you don't need to eval it, and if you are passing in a string you should be using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) anyway. Change the above to:

```
var Jsj = Data;
```

There are some other issues around the footer display being incorrect, unfortunately I haven't used jqGrid before (I prefer [datatables.net plugin](http://datatables.net/)). I would also suggest you stay away from variables names like `parse`, whilst strictly it is not a reserved word it is confusing

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/ZV4RT/1/)

Comment: Thanks @jammykam but i am getting error as i am passing my ajax response to my showJqGrid(Data) the error i am getting TypeError: Jsj.Header is undefined
 

for ( var i = 0; i < Jsj.Header.length; i++)

Comment: @Mayur Try adding the `dataType: "json"` property to your $.ajax request to the force the MIME type to json: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: how to use this with dataTable can you guide with any example

Comment: @Mayur There is lots of great documentation on that site, here is an example though: http://jsfiddle.net/jammykam/dGdAr/ Please raise another question and let me know if you get stuck and I'll help

Comment: The gqgrid when load more then 5000 records its take so much time and stops after certain minutes and loads half data only is there any other way to insert data

Comment: @Mayur I don't know unfortunately. You should try a different plugin maybe, just Google "jQuery Table Plugin" and try a few of them. You may have to delegate all operations (pagination, sorting etc) to the server so it only loads records as it needs them...